# Input and output, method call and stack frame

Tags: java, input, stack, frame

I'm currently learning input and output and I'm not sure about this question:

```
public static int foo(x) {
return 2*x;
}
```

Suppose the stack contains the following values on entry to foo, from bottom to top, as read left to right:

1 2 3

So 3 is on top and 1 is on the bottom.

Just after `foo` returns, will the stack be 1 2 6 or 6 2 1?
I thought the method would firstly take the value on top and return the value to the top of the stack again.

Comment: I don't understand your question, there is no recursivity here.

Comment: @ Dragos Rachieru No. But here I think it's more about the concept of stack frame? I'm not sure though.

Comment: I don't undersstand where you got 1 2 6 from, isn't it supposed to be 2 4 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you talk about the stack that the Java Virtual Machine uses internally (as defined in  [The JVM Specification, Java Virtual Machine Stacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2). Quite similar concepts exist in most contemporary programming languages.

Your assumption is correct, method calling and returning is done at top of the stack. So, `1 2 3` becomes `1 2 6` (that's why it's called a stack, it's hard to manipulate it at some deeply-buried position).